# Upload terminates in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Safari

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, browser

We try to upload a `csv` file bigger than 10 MB to an Apache server. The file should then, after upload, be processed by a PHP script. We set up the following settings on Apache and PHP:

```
upload_max_filesize = 48M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 2400
```

Now we are only able to upload and process file with Safari. Firefox and Chrome abort the upload with `500 error`.

Doing the same on the local LAMP installation this problem doesn't exist. What could be done to be able to upload and process files bigger than 10 MB in Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: A 500 error message is a blanket error message. More detail can be found within your server's error logs, and can give you a hint as to what the actual issue might be.

Comment: @aynber: did it - empty:(